# Targeting an iframe element using colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a link displaying the contents in the colorbox plugin via the iframe method and would like to target specific elements inside the iframe.

Can't seem to figure it out.  Below is where I am at...any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(".thickbox").colorbox({iframe:true,width:450, height:570, title: 'Form Title', 
   onComplete: function() {
    $("#cboxLoadedContent iframe").contents().find("a.login").css("display","none");
   } 
  });
```

Comment: can you explain the html structure of the page inside your iframe..

Answer (score 0):

I would use Firebug and set breakpoints so you can browse through the DOM and find the path you're looking for.

Break up that $("#cboxLoadedContent iframe")... line into multiple lines, set breakpoints on each to make sure you know where it's going wrong and debug from there.